# getting SSI's `exec` to work with apache

Tags: apache-2.4, server-side-includes

so i have an apache-2.4.25 (as packaged in Debian/stretch), and would like to use SSI's `exec` method.

```
<!--#exec cmd="ls" -->
```

Unfortunately this gives me an error:

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

In the logfiles it says

```
unknown directive "exec" in parsed doc /path/to/some/user/public_html/ssitest/index.shtml
```

which I tracked down to having `Options +IncludesNOEXEC` enabled in my `userdir.conf` (which disables the `exec` directive for SSI).
So I tried to turn that option off for a single specific VHost, by putting the following into the `VirtualHost` section:

```
Options -IncludesNOEXEC
Options +Includes
```

Unfortunately this doesn't help.

So I tried with in the `Directory` section, but still no luck:

```
Alias /ssitest/ /path/to/some/user/public_html/ssitest/
Options -IncludesNOEXEC
Options +Includes
<Directory /path/to/some/user/public_html/ssitest/>
  Options -IncludesNOEXEC
  Options +Includes
</Directory>
```

Whenever I try to access my page, I get the *an error occurred while processing this directive* error.

So is there a way to disable a previously set option?

Comment: Did you enable mod_cgi? Or mod_cgid?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mod_cgi. I now check ssi exec run on Ubuntu 16.04+apache2 - it works if you enable mod_include and mod_cgi, and put `Options +Includes` in htaccess or in `<Directory... >`.

`Options -IncludesNOEXEC` wasn't needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu, apache2 web server
enable the mod, with the following commands

```sh
a2dismod cgi
```

and with

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
vim 000-default.conf
```

add the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/httpdocs>
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    Options +Includes
</Directory>
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think `a2dismod` disables a module instead of enabling it.